# Magento 2 : cashondelivery.phtml file custom code not show

Tags: magento2, template, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

First I try to modify the code directly of core file.

```
vendor\magento\module-offline-payments\view\frontend\templates\form\cashondelivery.phtml
```

I added testing code like this.

```
<?php $instructions = $block->getInstructions(); ?>
<?php if ($instructions): ?>
    <?php echo "MY CUSTOM CODE HERE"; ?>
    <?php $methodCode = $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethodCode());?>
    <div class="items <?= /* @noEscape */ $methodCode ?> instructions agreement" id="payment_form_<?= /* @noEscape */ $methodCode ?>" style="display: none;">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ nl2br($block->escapeHtml($instructions)) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here I have one question.

Where my custom message show? Currently it not showing my message any where on checkout???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to work on `vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html`

As magento2 manage checkout steps manage from knockout js & UI element. So you have to copy **cashondelivery.html** to

> app/design/frontend/{ThemeVendor}/{Themename}/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html

and Do add this text to here.

Then do static content deploy and cache flush.

### By Custom module

Create `requirejs-config.js` at `/app/code/{VenDorName}/{Module}/view/frontend`.
Override the knockout js using and it code

**`requirejs-config.js`  code is below**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method' : '{VenDorName}_{Module}/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method',
        }
    }
};
```

Create knock view file `cashondelivery-method.js` at `/app/code/{VenDorName}/{Module}/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/`.

and code is

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: '{VenDorName}_{Module}/payment/cashondelivery'
        },

        /**
         * Returns payment method instructions.
         *
         * @return {*}
         */
        getInstructions: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
        }
    });
});
```

And copy **`vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html`** to

`/app/code/{VenDorName}/{Module}/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html`

**After that you  have to do  Static content deploy**

Comment: I want to overide file into custom extension not theme, what to do?

Answer (score 1):

`module-offline-payments\view\frontend\templates\form\cashondelivery.phtml` is for **Check Out with Multiple Addresses**

Comment: ok let me check and is that any same file for single address check out?

Answer (score 0):

Above answer using theme is not working because need to create folder having name **Magento_OfflinePayments** in theme.

So the Actual path in your custom theme to override this file will be:

**app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html**